# How Do I change from PTP to MTP mode? Cannot find options in settings

Tags: video, android-pc

That may be the issue why I can't see my captured videos from my phone when connected to my pc. How do I access PTP and MTP modes? Can't see any options in settings.

Comment: What phone do you have? What Android version does it have?

Comment: Do you not see a USB connection notification when you connect your phone into PC via USB cable? See if [this answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/111718/96277) helps. Alternatively, enable USB debugging, install ADB in PC and try `adb shell am start com.android.settings/.UsbSettings` in Command Prompt.

Comment: My phone is a SC-04Fm version 5. The first time it showed the USB icon but not anymore. I can see the folders when pc connected but no videos shown. I will try installing adb in pc.

Comment: Well, downloaded the adb driver installer but it doesn't execute. Error message: Device Not Found.

Comment: Also, when I go to seetings->storage there no more available options.

Answer (score 10):

You can do that via [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) or a [terminal](/questions/tagged/terminal) app (in the latter case, ommit the leading `adb shell` from the examples):

- read settings: `adb shell getprop sys.usb.config`
- find valid settings: `adb shell grep usb.config= /init*rc`
- change settings: `setprop` with the appropriate values (e.g. `adb shell setprop sys.usb.config "mtp,adb"` or `adb shell setprop sys.usb.config "ptp,adb"`)

**EDIT:** If the above doesn't yield the expected results, it might need root powers. So if your device is rooted, you could try to run `adb root` prior to above commands. If your device does not accept this ("not available in production builds"), instead run:

```
PC> adb shell
Android $ su
Android #
```

Now at the root prompt (`#`), run above commands without the `adb shell` prefix (e.g. simply `setprop sys.usb.config "mtp,adb"`).

Comment: Thanks for this.  When I connect my device to OSX it doesn't show the USB connection type toggle, and Android File Transfer doesn't seem to work with MTP mode.  This let me switch it to PTP.

Comment: Also, for completeness, you'll have to run `adb root` first to have the permission to change the setting.

Comment: @Ullallulloo are you sure about that? I cannot remember ever having done that. And the only times I tried, I got an error about `adb root` being not available "in production builds".

Comment: @Izzy It silently fails on both my phones without that. `adb root` only solves it on the rooted one though. The unrooted phone doesn't seem to allow me to change it over adb.

Comment: Thanks, @Ullallulloo – adjusted my answer accordingly. Thinking about it, as I usually placed the settings directly into the proper scripts on the device, I might have executed `setprop` while already being root – at least after the first tries to figure this out years ago ;)

Comment: it changes the property yes, but it doesn't really enable mtp mode, this is useless, there is something else has to be changed to really trigger mtp mode

Comment: @user924 it did perfectly back then. Take a look at the date, there were several newer Android versions released since, and something might have changed. I no longer have this issue on any of my devices, so I cannot tell.