# Change USB connection mode using ADB only (broken screen)

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, usb-connection-mode, motorola-moto-g5

I am trying to use Vysor to control my Moto G5 which has a broken screen (completely black). It appears to be working otherwise (rings when called etc).

However, I cannot connect to my PC using USB cable when the phone is on, because I cannot change from "Charging only" to MTP or PTP because I cannot see it on the screen. I can connect to ADB via recovery (stock and un-rooted) but all "adb shell" commands fail (error:closed) which I assume is due to not being rooted.

I am trying to change the default USB connection mode to PTP rather than "Charging only" so I can use Vysor when the phone is booted normally, not in recovery. Has anyone got any ideas?

I either need a way to made "adb shell" commands work (to follow the below link), or another way to change the USB default or another bright idea!

[How Do I change from PTP to MTP mode? Cannot find options in settings](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/120026/how-do-i-change-from-ptp-to-mtp-mode-cannot-find-options-in-settings)

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP hasn't visited the site after posting the question, and no answers have score above 0). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

Late as I am to the party the following might be of some help:-

https://trubitsyn.dev/posts/adb-connectivity

The command `svc usb setFunction <mtp|ptp|rndis|midi>` is the most likely candidate (alternatively **`setFunctions`** is used dependant on the version of Android.

Comment: Link seems to be dead.